# typedef to store pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

The Size of pointer depends on the arch of the machine.

So 
sizeof(int*)=sizeof(int) or sizeof(int*)=sizeof(long int)

I want to have a custom data type which is either int or long int depending on the size of pointer.

I tried to use macro #if, but the condition for macros does not allow sizeof operator.

Also when using if-else, typedef is limited to the scope of if.

```
if((sizeof(int)==sizeof(int *)){
  typedef int ptrtype;
}
else{
  typedef long int ptrtype;
}
//ptrtype not avialble here
```

Is there any way to define ptrtype globally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traditional way to do this used to be to use GNU autoconf (or similar) to set up some defines such as `SIZEOF_VOIDPTR`, but if you have a sufficiently recent compiler the type `intptr_t` may well be what you want. (You might need to set some compiler flags to enable C99 mode; it's in `<stdint.h>`.)

Answer (score 7):

In C99 you can use `intptr_t`.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` defined in `<stdint.h>`.